# Salesforce as an OpenID Connect provider with Azure B2C as a Relying Party

Tags: identity, open-id-connect, azure-active-directory

I am working on a prototype to do federated authentication through Azure AD (AAD) B2C.  I have successfully linked my prototype to a separate Azure AD tenant using OpenID Connect and have it working.  When trying to integrate Salesforce as an OpenID Connect provider AAD responds with an error of "The provided id_token does not contain a valid audience".  In my connected app under ID Token Audiences I have added the Client Id of the Azure AD B2C app but I continue to get the same error.

Can anyone suggest a course of action?

Comment: The error message is "The provided `id_token`", not just a (generic) "token". It's an Azure AD (AAD) error message...and while it may have something to do with configuration of the connected app, what has to go into the connected app is dictated by AAD and your specific implementation of AAD. Have you tried asking on the Azure AD forum or StackOverflow?

Comment: @identigral I have engaged with them as well.  I have setup other IDP providers with OpenID and successfully integrated them in my protoype.  The odd thing is that they did not ask for a Token Audience when setting them up.  If I leave that field blank in SalesForce then I received a mal-formed token error.  Based off of the success with other IDPs and the error when that field is blank I still feel it's a configuration issue with Salesforce I don't know how to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenID Connect protocol](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) in brief:

> - The RP (Client) sends a request to the OpenID Provider (OP).
> - The OP authenticates the End-User and obtains authorization.
> - The OP responds with an ID Token and possibly an Access Token.
> - The RP can send a request with the Access Token to the UserInfo Endpoint.
> - The UserInfo Endpoint returns Claims about the End-User.

In your case RP = Azure AD (AAD), OP = Salesforce.

Some claims in ID token are specified by [OIDC protocol](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), `aud`(ience) is one of them:

> `aud` - REQUIRED. Audience(s) that this ID Token is intended for. It MUST
> contain the OAuth 2.0 `client_id` of the Relying Party as an audience
> value. It MAY also contain identifiers for other audiences. In the
> general case, the `aud` value is an array of case sensitive strings. In
> the common special case when there is one audience, the `aud` value MAY
> be a single case sensitive string.

Based on this paragraph, you must have AAD B2C app's `client_id` be available in the `aud` claim of `id_token` issued by Salesforce. You tried implementing this by using ID Token Audiences in the connected app. Unfortunately the dual-purpose nature of connected app in Salesforce world plays against you here. Since Salesforce can be either or both RP or OP in OIDC context and the same connected app can be used for both flows, the `aud` value always contains the `client_id` of the connected app.

When you enter a value or series of values in ID Token Audiences, Salesforce takes these values and appends them to Salesforce's own `client_id` to generate the value of `aud` claim. To illustrate this, entering `https://foo.bar.com` in ID Token Audiences and NOT selecting Standard Claims for brevity yields this `id_token` (values are redacted):

```javascript
{
     "at_hash": "...",
     "aud": "3MVG...RAT,https://foo.bar.com",
     "exp": ...,
     "iat": ...,
     "iss": "...",
     "sub": "..."
}
```

The `3MVG...RAT` is a redacted value of connected app's own `client_id` and `https://foo.bar.com` is appended to that using comma as a separator.

Is Salesforce compliant with OpenID Connect spec here insofar as the value of `aud` claim goes? Maybe.

- Does it contain the `client id` of the Relying Party? Sort of, depending on your definition of RP in general versus this specific case.
- Does it allow you to enter identifiers for "other" audiences? Yes, via ID Token Audiences.
- If more than one identifier is stuffed into the value of `aud`, is there an array of strings? Sort of. The specification does not say `JSON array` so one could claim that a comma-separated set of strings represents an array. A weak claim, this one.

Now let's look at AAD. It receives an `id_token` with `aud` set to comma-separated string with AAD B2C app's `client_id` somewhere in there, assuming you've added it to the connected app via ID Token Audiences. As a Relying Party, AAD will attempt to validate the value of `aud` claim and it fails in doing so. If you hang out with lawyers and you narrowly interpret the spec wording of *`aud` value is an array of case sensitive strings* as (any) array rather than a JSON array, then AAD is at fault here. You provided the value of AAD B2C app's `client_id`, it made it to `aud` and AAD (allegedly!) failed to notice.

Reality check: most RPs and OPs treat the wording of *`aud` value is an array of case sensitive strings* to mean a JSON array. Therefore, this is a Salesforce product bug. You should open a support case with SF and formally pursue it. Furthermore, not being able to have the SF admin configuring the connected app specify whether it's acting as RP or OP is another issue. Feel free to mention this to SF support.

As far as what you should do to fix this - we recommend you switch to SAML.